# Group by on multiple tables

Tags: oracle

Need query for below expected output

**Tbl1**

```
Pol id  superpolid
100      900
101      900
102      901
103      901
104      903
```

**Tbl2**

```
Polid custid
100    1122
101    1122
102    1122
103    1122
104    1133
```

**Expected output**

```
Custid count(Superpolid)
1122    2
1133    1
```

Comment: Please, show your attempt and describe what is your problem. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a join with aggregation. Sample data in lines #1 - 15, query begins at line #16.

```
SQL> with
  2  tbl1 (polid, superpolid) as
  3    (select 100, 900 from dual union all
  4     select 101, 900 from dual union all
  5     select 102, 901 from dual union all
  6     select 103, 901 from dual union all
  7     select 104, 903 from dual
  8    ),
  9  tbl2 (polid, custid) as
 10    (select 100, 1122 from dual union all
 11     select 101, 1122 from dual union all
 12     select 102, 1122 from dual union all
 13     select 103, 1122 from dual union all
 14     select 104, 1133 from dual
 15    )
 16  select b.custid,
 17         count(distinct a.superpolid) cnt
 18  from tbl1 a join tbl2 b on a.polid = b.polid
 19  group by b.custid
 20  order by b.custid;

    CUSTID        CNT
---------- ----------
      1122          2
      1133          1

SQL>
```